# CSS - repeat only down part of an image

Tags: css, background

I have this picture:

[image]

And I would like to print this picture as background on the top of my page. After 661px in height (this is height of this picture), I would like to repeat-y only down part of this image. I think in width 100% and in height 10px from bottom of this picture. Finally I would like to have this picture on the top and then all page under this background should be grey.

I tried like that:

```
background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zGno.png) center top no-repeat, url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zGno.png) repeat 100% 10px scroll;
```

but it doesn't work fine. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: http://s10.ifotos.pl/img/demopng_swqepqn.png - this is not the same colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make such complex graphical works with css. You have to make an appropriate image with Photoshop (or similar).